# Filter an array with Observable.from

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

1) I get array of objects from the server. This array has information about all authors. I've built this in component called: `AnalyticsDataComponent` and display a list with all authors and it's data.

2) I have create component called `WriterComponent` in which I want to display only the data that belongs to user. Because I don't want to send request again to the server and get the response with that data I have create `ShareService` to share the whole array. With my `WriterComponent` I try to filter the array so I get only the correct data. I use for this the `Observable.from` but not effectively.

**Routes**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'data', component: AnalyticsDataComponent},
    {path: 'writer/:writerID', component: WriterComponent}
];
```

**AnalyticsDataComponent**

```
export class AnalyticsDataComponent implements OnInit {

    analyticsData: Array<AnalyticsData>;
    overall: Object;
    loading: boolean;
    ready: boolean;
    whileLoding: boolean = true;
    year: string = '2016';
    month: string = '10';
    startDate: string;
    endDate: string;
    public months = Month;

    constructor(
        private services: AnalyticsDataService,
        private cookie: CookieService,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private shareService: ShareService
    ) {
        this.analyticsData = [];
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.auth.redirectNotAuthUser();
        this.setDateRange(
            {
                'year': this.year,
                'month': this.month,
            }
        );
    }

    setDateRange(value) {
        this.year = value.year;
        this.month = value.month;
        if (value.year && value.month) {
            this.whileLoding = false;
            let month = value.month;
            let lastDate = new Date(value.year, month, 1).toISOString().split('T')[0];
            this.startDate = value.year + '-' + value.month + '-' + '01';
            this.endDate = lastDate;
            this.getData();
        }
    }

    getData() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.ready = false;
        this.services.getData(this.cookie.get(), this.startDate, this.endDate)
            .subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.overall = response.overall;
                response.data.forEach((element: any, index: number) => {
                    this.analyticsData.push(
                        new AnalyticsData({
                       pagePath: element.pagePath,
                        pageTitle: element.pageTitle,
                        wholeProfit: element.wholeProfit,
                        uniquePageView: element.uniquePageView,
                        entrance: element.entrance,
                        avgTime: element.avgTime,
                        bounceRate: element.bounceRate,
                        pageView: element.pageView,
                        author: element.author
                        })
                    );
                });
                this.loading = false;
                this.ready = true;
                this.whileLoding = true;
            },
            (error) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.whileLoding = true;
                console.log('Error happened' + error);
            },
            () => {

                this.shareService.analyticsData = this.analyticsData;
                this.shareService.overallData = this.overall;
                console.log('the subscription is completed');
            }
            );
    }
}
```

**WriterComponent**

```
export class WriterComponent implements OnInit {

  writerID: number;
  writerData: Array<Object>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private shareService: ShareService) {
    route.params.subscribe(params => { this.writerID = params['writerID']; });
    this.writerData = [];

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterData();
  }


  filterData() {
    if (this.shareService.analyticsData !== undefined) {
      this.shareService.analyticsData.forEach(element => {
        Observable.from([element])
          .filter(data => data.author.user_id === this.writerID)
          .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.writerData.push(
              new AnalyticsData({
            pagePath: data.pagePath,
            pageTitle: data.pageTitle,
            wholeProfit: data.wholeProfit,
            uniquePageView: data.uniquePageView,
            entrance: data.entrance,
            avgTime: data.avgTime,
            bounceRate: data.bounceRate,
            pageView: data.pageView,
            author: data.author
              })
            );
          },
          err => {
            console.error(err);
          }
          );
      });
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: What extra data property do you want to get where? `Observable.from()` seems a bit pointless if you don't return it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have an array with users data with in my main component. Now I have create `auhor.component` in which I want to get only the data that belongs to user. From the main component the user can select one author and then the routing system send to the `auhor.component` with the user id. I have `ShareService` so I can get the whole array from every componernt

Comment: I still don't get what the problem is. Instead of prose (or in addition to prose) can you please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've updated my question. Thank you and sorry for my poor english. If you want some more tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.filterData();
  }

  filterData() {
    if (this.shareService.analyticsData !== undefined) {
      return this.shareService.analyticsData
      .filter(data => data.author.user_id === this.writerID)
      .map(data => {
          new AnalyticsData({
            pagePath: element.pagePath,
            pageTitle: element.pageTitle,
            wholeProfit: element.wholeProfit,
            uniquePageView: element.uniquePageView,
            entrance: element.entrance,
            avgTime: element.avgTime,
            bounceRate: element.bounceRate,
            pageView: element.pageView,
            author: element.author
          })
      });
    } 
    return Observable.of([]);
  }
```

and then bind to the data like

```
[someInputThatUsesData]="data | async"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Again the property  `this.writerID ` is not reached

Comment: I don't know what you mean with `this.writerID` is not reached. Perhaps it's not yet set when the filter in `filterData()` is executed.

Comment: Sorry. I get `writerID` property.  Within the `map callback`. I try to `console.log(data)` but I get nothing...

Comment: `return this.shareService.analyticsData
        .filter(data => data.author.user_id === this.writerID)
        .map(data => {
          console.log(data);`

Comment: Where do you get `writerID` property?

Comment: Generally whatever I try to console within `.map` does not executed

Comment: From the route I get the writerID. If I try to console the writerID in the `.filter` it's ok.

Comment: I don't understand at all where its ok and where not. Perhaps there is no author with a matching `user_id`. I can't verify this from here.

Comment: Another very strange thing. If I try to add writerID hardcoded It works. The problem is with the property `writerID`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (as mentioned above already) that the `writerID` property is not yet set when the filter is executed.

Comment: Sorry men. It's ok. The problem is with the type `==='. The one is string and the other integer :)

Comment: Another thing. Typescript give me an error for the returning type `Observable.of([]);`  `No best common type exists among return expressions`

Comment: Perpaps `return Observable<AnalyticsData>.of([]);` or `return Observable.of<AnalyticsData>([]);` (I'm not familiar with TS generics syntax).

Comment: Is `return Observable.of([]);` necessary. As I can see It works and without this.

Comment: Depends on how you use this method. It's not necessary if the caller can handle `null` responses.